# How do I transpose a column in my dataframe keeping everything else the same

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am setting up my data-frame for analysis. However, this is my first time where I need a conditional transpose.

I have a data-frame like follows:

```
 F_Name  L_Name id Booking_date flag
1    Alon Trecker  1   10/16/2018    A
2    Alon Trecker  1    1/15/2019    B
3 Tenzing   Omaho  2    8/29/2018    A
4 Tenzing   Omaho  2   12/26/2018    A
5  Sheryl   Stark NA   11/20/2018    A
```

I want to split the column Booking_date such that for each person or each record there are two booking dates `Booking_date1` and `Booking_date2` where the value of the first column would be the first date of the `Booking_date´ column for that person and the second one would be the second entry. However, if the person doesn't has a second entry I can leave him with NA value on Booking_date2 column.

Something like this

```
F_Name  L_Name id Booking_date1 Booking_date2 flag1 flag2
Alon    Trecker 1    10/16/2018     1/15/2019     A     B
Tenzing  Omaho  2     8/29/2018    12/26/2018     A     A
Sheryl   Stark  NA   11/20/2018            NA     A    NA
```

I have tried using `melt` and `spread` but I have no idea of using it. if anyone can help me on this it would be great.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, date_id := 1:.N, by = .(id)]
dcast(df, ... ~ date_id, value.var = c("Booking_date", "flag"))
#     F_Name  L_Name id Booking_date_1 Booking_date_2 flag_1 flag_2
# 1:    Alon Trecker  1     10/16/2018      1/15/2019      A      B
# 2:  Sheryl   Stark NA     11/20/2018           <NA>      A   <NA>
# 3: Tenzing   Omaho  2      8/29/2018     12/26/2018      A      A
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of Cettt, you have to remove column flag in order to have one row per person. Besides, you should convert the booking date to a datetime class  variable (`ymd` function of `lubridate` package) to be sure to keep the order of the booking date

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
myadta %>% 
  group_by(F_Name, L_Name) %>% 
  mutate(Booking_date = mdy(Booking_date),
         Booking_id = paste0("Booking_date", row_number(Booking_date))) %>% 
  select(-flag) %>% 
  spread(Booking_id, Booking_date)
```

Comment: Yes, I though that so. However, the answer from Gregor did solve my issue I can now create dummies for flag and get unique entries too. becuase value of flag can only have A or B.